# create Function.prototype.theSame so that f() can be invoked as f.theSame()

Tags: javascript

I would like to create an alias for every function so that instead of calling:

```
f();
```

I can just call:

```
f.theSame();
```

... and have the same effect.
There's no reason for that, just curiosity.

By using `Function.prototype` this appears to be easy:

```
Function.prototype.theSame = function() {
    return this(arguments);
};

var foo = function foo() {return 1;};

console.log(foo.theSame()); // prints 1 - OK
```

The problem appears when I realize that the above doesn't work on "member functions" because the `this` is hidden:

```
var a = {x: 3, f: function() {return this.x;}};

console.log(a.f()); // prints 3 - OK

// throws TypeError: object is not a function
console.log(a.f.theSame.apply(a, []));

console.log(a.f.theSame()); // prints undefined
```

So one has to do something like:

```
Function.prototype.theSame2 = function() {
    var fn = this;
    return function() {
        return fn.apply(this, arguments);
    };
};
```

Which, however, requires the `()()` awkward construct:

```
console.log(a.f.theSame2()()); // prints 3 - OK
```

Is there a way to implement `theSame` such that it works for "member functions" without using the `()()` construct?

Comment: `a.f.theSame2()()` doesn't actually work. It will print the global `x` variable, not `a.x`.

Comment: Your first example wouldn't work as expected when passing arguments. You should have `this.apply(null, arguments)`, where `null` is whatever you want the default *thisArg* to be for the invocation.

Comment: Your second example that is failing will only work (not throw) if you pass `a.f` as the first argument to `.apply`. Otherwise you're trying to make `this` in `theSame` represent 2 different things. So any function that relies on `this` isn't going to work out.

Comment: @Bergi I think you are mistaken, there's no global `x` variable and I tested it by modifying the property `x` in the `a` object - it does report the value `a.x`

Comment: @MarcusJuniusBrutus: I cannot reproduce. It just logs `undefined`, not `3`. Can you set up a demo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. If you call the function with `a.f.theSame()` then you are calling `f` as property of itself (i.e. `this` refers to the function itself). There is no "connection" from the function to the containing object, since a function is just a value and could be a property of many objects.

In order to make your example work you have to perform an additional initialization step that ties the function to `a`, e.g.

```
a.f = a.f.bind(a);
```

There is no way around this.

Comment: …or use `a.f.theSame(a)` (a.k.a. `call`)